# Joomla - hide image in header once user has logged in

Tags: joomla1.5

I'm pretty fresh to programming (have started doing Codeacademy this year and am enjoying it) and I have asked this question on other forums to no avail, even though I am sure it can be done.

I want to hide an image in my header of a Joomla site if the user is logged in, but I'm really not sure how to do this.

I know I would have to use the if/else values but I'm not sure how to piece it all together.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: My gut feeling is that this is going to be a bit more complicated than you think. Joomla definitely does not have this capability right out of the box. You might need to create your own component/module for this which is definitely not trivial.

Comment: I know I can use a plugin to control when modules display - I guess this might be the easiest route to take. But I thought I could use javascript to call on whether the user is logged in and adjust the display property of the item. Maybe I'm way off and trying to mash together too many things!?

Comment: I do not know. I did some Joomla development about 3 years ago... things probably changed a lot since then. If I could I definitely would go the module/component route. It will probably save you a lot of headaches down the line plus you learn more by creating a module/component instead of just hacking something in...

Answer (score 1):

You haven't given enough information to give a better answer at this point.

If you put the image in a module, then you can use Advanced Module Manager (free extensions) to turn the module off when the visitor is logged in.

The best way to do it would be to upgrade to the latest version of Joomla and use the built in ACL to control what is displayed. The 1.5 series reaches end of life in April so now would be a good time to switch.

Here is how you would set up the ACL in 1.7/2.5:

http://docs.joomla.org/Access_Control_List/1.6-2.5/Tutorial#Allowing_Guest-Only_Access_to_Menu_Items_and_Modules

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you can do :

```
$user =& JFactory::getUser();
if($user->id)
{
    //display the image
}
else
{
    //do not display the image
}
```

Comment: This looks along the lines of what I was thinking.

Comment: Forgive my ignorance, but where would I be placing this code?